# Ninject multiple modules

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject-2

I didnt think this would be a problem originally, but as I keep getting exceptions thought I would post here incase im being an idiot...

I have 2 module classes, one sets up NHibernate and one sets up MVC Controllers, now the problem I have is that I have something like below:

```
public class NHibernateModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<ISessionManager>().To<SessionManager>();
    }
}

public class ControllerModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<SomeController>().ToSelf()
                             .WithConstructorArgument("sessionManager", Kernel.Get<ISessionManager>());
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to use the controller, it just bombs out telling me that its having problems binding the sessionManager argument. I make sure the list has the Nhibernate module in before the Controller module when I create the kernel.

Is there anything immediately stupid in what im doing above?

Comment: I was being a total muppet, it ends up that one of my parameters was wrong sessionKey != sessionkey. Although I have learned that Ninject can infer the parameters rather than me having to type them all out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISessionManager _sessionManager;
    public HomeController(ISessionManager sessionManager)
    {
        _sessionManager = sessionManager;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The following should be sufficient:

```
public class NHibernateModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<ISessionManager>().To<SessionManager>();
    }
}

public class ControllerModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<SomeController>().ToSelf();
    }
}
```

and in Global.asax:

```
public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }

    protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var modules = new INinjectModule[]
        {
            new NHibernateModule(),
            new ControllerModule()
        };

        return new StandardKernel(modules);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are pretty spot on, I didnt know Ninject could infer parameters automatically, thats pretty sweet. I am not using NinjectHttpApplication though as I dont like my Http stuff being tied to it, so im using the DependencyResolver instead. Will give this a try though thanks!

Comment: Just gave it a go and get "System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object." The ISessionManager implementation has some constructor injection but thats all taken care of within the NHibernate module, and I didnt think it relevant as it may complicate the question.